# Byte padding issue on cross arch

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, padding, named-pipes

I have noticed that sizzeof() on my program structure is different on x86 and x64 platform. This is becaue of bytes padding. Due to one requirement (where my application talks between cross arch m/c), i need to make sure that target should get the same size of structure what sender had send through a nammedpipe (in my case, i can not read pipe again for remaining data..). I need a way in C++ if i can disable/enable padding safely or strip padding bytes before using sizeof() operator on that structure.

Thanks..

[EDIT | CONCLUSION]: just an input for others who try to seek solution for similar issue. Tried a lot many stupid things to get around this issue but one possible solution mentioned here created the problem in another way, debugging of which time-taking. The best option to this problem i could find out is to use serialization and deserialization methods as 'R..' has mentioned below.

Comment: Are you sure this is just a padding issue?  The result of `sizeof` in general (apart from `sizeof(char)`) is platform dependent.

Comment: Then what it could be. The same structure on x64 with sizeof operator showing "336" bytes while with x86 arch it is showing "316" bytes. I can not think other reason beside padding.

Comment: There's another thing than padding, some types don't have the same size between x86 and x64. `long` `void *` `size_t` and all their derived types have differing sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type #pragma pack(1) before your structure it should disable padding. This works on both visual studio and gcc. You probably also want to use #pragma pack(push) and #pragma pack(pop) to save and restore the previous padding rules.
For example:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct
{
...
};
#pragma(pop)
```

Comment: This is more like what i want. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: This is a very bad idea. You should instead write proper serialize and deserialize methods. Packing structures incorrectly will lead to broken code unless you're very careful...

Comment: but i thought serialization has no relation with memory padding. Am i wrong??

Comment: What I think he means is that instead of streaming the entire structure, you can stream each individual member by using functions like WriteUInt16(...) and on the other side you can use ReadInt16. That way you control everything and padding doesn't matter.

Comment: They may work for you but remember than on many architectures you'll get an error if you try to access unaligned data. So you're better to set the alignment to a value that's suitable for all your architectures than (1)

Comment: As long as you don't try to take a pointer to a member of the struct, access to unaligned members will work on all platforms.  (Granted, the generated code is slower, but it won't crash.)

Comment: Serialization in this case is: never threat a struct as a data type corresponding directly to a communication protocol (or hardware registers). Packing and unpacking data in and out of the communication protocol is necessary for robust code. Though of course if the protocol was saved as an array of bytes rather than a struct, you wouldn't need that.

Comment: @servn: that doesn't make sense. On most non-x86 platforms, there's no such thing as "unaligned members". There all members are aligned, unaligned access is only possible via pointers, and it will crash.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid writing code that is using sizeof of a struct/union. For portability, use sizeof on the individual members instead:

```
const int struct_size = sizeof(x.member1) + sizeof(x.member2) + ...;
```

Comment: but what if member's data size differ on both platform..??

Comment: Presumably he is transmitting these structs over a socket, so he really needs to made sure that both ends of the socket agree on the size AND location of all the fields in the struct.  I don't think this answer addresses that.  Maybe you have a different interpretation of the problem?

Comment: That could be one possiblity, but in my case struct is bit longer (15 elements) and i dont think this would be clearner approach. I might take this approach and accept ur ans, as last resort if no other cleaner way possible.

Comment: This approach will have problems if you are sending the structs as an array. For that, making the padding and size consistent is unavoidable, unless you get rid of the structs completely and use arrays of each of the member fields.

Comment: This is the problem-free approach. Disabling padding on a specific compiler is not portable. What isn't clean about it? You have to add 15 more rows in your program... so? sizeof is evaluated at compile time so you can hide the whole thing away from the actual program and just use the constant.

Answer (score 2):

What compiler are you using?  You can use GCC's `packed` attribute to tell the compiler to not add any padding in your struct.  Other compilers probably have a similar feature.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

The `aligned` attribute might help you as well.

Comment: Disabling padding on a specific compiler does not make the code portable.

Comment: That's not really the point... the point is to make the compiler treat the struct the correct/predictable way, so that your executable can correctly send and receive the struct with other instances over a socket.  The original poster did not use the word "portable" in his question, he just wanted his program to work.  Anyway, you can make it portable by adding #ifdefs for every compiler you want to support.

Comment: Why fiddle around with compiler options instead of writing the C code portable though? The C standard clearly states that a compiler is free to add any number of padding bytes anywhere in the struct except before the very first element. It isn't really that hard to write code which makes no assumptions about padding and alignment.

Comment: How would you send the entire struct over the socket?  One field at a time?  I guess that works, but then you have to maintain multiple lists of all the fields in the struct.  Its nicer if you can just send the whole struct as a binary block of data, i.e. starting at `(char *)mystruct` with size `sizeof(mystruct)`.  To do that, you need to get control over where all the fields are placed.  My answer shows how to do that.

Comment: I wouldn't have used a struct for a data protocol unless I was certain that my code would never be ported. If portability is desired, I'd use an array of bytes for the protocol. If the programmer can't handle that array but badly craves a struct, then some code for packing/unpacking between the array and the struct has to be written. When writing portable code you often end up with such packing code regardless, as most data protocols specify a specific endianess.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to also make sure that you are using arch-independent elements of structure - if two different arch's have - say - different size of int, then removing padding will not help. Try to use stdint.h types instead eg. int32_t instead of int.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that in addition to padding, the sizes of the types may vary between architectures.  In addition to that, endianness could vary too (not between 32 and 64 bit Intel, but if others are thrown it it could be an issue).

So serialization is a good idea.  Basically just create a function for writing and one for reading for each architecture.

The write function would write each relevant byte of each structure member, with the members written in a known order, and the bytes of each member also in a known order (say, most significant first).  If the sizes of a type vary between platforms, write as many bytes of the type as all platforms will support.

The read function should do the reverse of what the write function does, and zero any bytes that aren't included in the serialized data.  The functions aren't hard to write, and using them makes the padding, endianness and (often) sizes of basic types irrelevant.

Comment: Also, the data protocols themselves often specify endianess. It's not the case with Windows pipes as in this question, however.